# How can a script check if my local server is running?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

Before version 1.7.2 I was able to check if the server was running by using a shellscript that checked if `server.log.lck` was in the Minecraft server directory. I am running multiple servers via screens, so I want to be sure that the server is not running before I start it.
Because 1.7.2 introduced a new logging system, this is not possible anymore.

I use a shell script where I have an unique port and an unique screen name for each server.

How can I now determine if the server is running?

Comment: What operating system are you using? (This is trivial under unix-like systems, so I'm guessing Windows?)

Comment: I am running Debian.

Comment: Ah, so using `ps` isn't a trivial option, because you have more than one process.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie: Wouldn't you be able to pipe `ps` into `grep` and check that way?  Also, there might be another lock file that you can check.

Comment: @MBraedley Yeah, but if they're all identical commands (differing only by *where* they're launched), then they will look the same in `ps` and there's nothing to grep for. I believe you can run using a full path to the jar instead of relative and then you can grep on the directories in the path, but I don't have a system to test that behaviour's reliability on. (My nearest *nix is OS X, and it notoriously tweaks command line tools in ways that make them subtly different.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I sorted it out by using the following if in my shell script:

```
if ! screen -list | grep -q $SCREEN_NAME; then
    ONLINE=1
else
    ONLINE=0
fi
```

Where $SCREEN_NAME is the server's unique screen name.

Comment: Nice, and a very clean solution.